# keyup event only gets value from first input where multiple are available in a table with same name and id

Tags: javascript, laravel, keyup

[image: here keyup function only takes value from first norvic id field and does not from second.]

this is the input field

```
<input name ="norvic_id" id="norvic_id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Norvic ID">
```

this is the script

```
<script>
    $('#norvic_id').keyup(function() {
            var x = $('input[name=norvic_id]').val();
            $("#nid").val(x);
    });
</script>
```

nid is hidden input value in a form where i am sending the data from the norvic_id field

```
{!!Form::open(['method'=>'POST','route'=>['newpatients.store'], 'class'=>'form-horizontal
                                bordered-row','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
                                <input name ="nid" id="nid" type="hidden" value="" class="form-control">
                                <input name ="pid" id="pid" type="hidden" value="{{$d->id}}" class="form-control">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-sm btn-success btn_glyph" id="confirm">Confirm</button>
                            {!!Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ids must be unique in all the website.

You can set a `norvic_id` class to that inputs:

And then use the class selector in jQuery:

```
$('.norvic_id').keyup(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $("#nid").val(x);
});
```